# If I am Sending Emails On Port 587 Why Do I Need To Allow Port 25 In My Firewall For Postfix

Tags: smtp, postfix

I am using my postfix smtp to send ONLY **outgoing** emails. It will not receive **incoming** messages. I have my mailbox at Namecheap for that.

I use a client called Mailwizz to connect my Postfix SASL user credentials. This happens on port 587.

I ran a test and the emails deliver without issues.

Question:
If I am sending emails using `port 587` on Mailwizz, **why do I need to allow `port 25` in my firewall?** **What would happen if I disable `port 25`?**

Also, I am confused if I should allow port 587 AND/OR listening via TCP.

**Do I run these two commands:**

```
sudo ufw allow 587

sudo ufw allow 587/tcp
```

**Or just one suffices? If so, which one?**

Comment: Mailwizz has a port and the server has a port you only have to port forward the server.

Comment: Furthermore if the email is actually being sent and received you don’t have to forward anything

Comment: @Ramhound This doesnt answer my question. Mailwizz is asking for my mail server's port (i.e. 25, 465, 587, 2525, etc.) Mailwizz doesnt have a port. I connect my smtp server and tell it what port my mail server is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you described you do not need to open port 25 - this would only be required if you were receiving emails from other mail servers on the Internet.

With respect of your firewall rules, only 1 is required (but either will do).  The second - "ufw allow 587/tcp" is the better of the 2 rules as it is tighter.  (This allows UDP traffic on port 587 - which is not used by mail - in practice this is a somewhat theoretical concern).     If you go with "ufw allow 587", the second rule which specifies TCP is redundant and will not do anything useful for you.

Simplifying a little, SMTP mail delivery has to modes - MUA to MTA and MTA to MTA.      MUA stands for "Mail User Agent" - which is something like an Outlook or Thunderbird mail client, while MTA is a "Mail Transfer Agent".

MTA to MTA delivery requires that the port 25 be open as there it is possible that mail will go in either direction and needs to use the defined standard ports as there is nothing pre-agreed between the servers.

**MUA to MTA delivery can take place over an arbitrary port - because the port can be programmed in the MUA.   It is common to use port 587.  Port 25 is not used at all in this scenario.    This is the mode that you are using.**

There is then the secondary question "well, after the MUA delivers mail to the MTA, how does my MTA handle it".   The answer is that it makes an OUTBOUND connection **from** an arbitrary port TO port 25 on the remote server.  This is an outbound connection, not an inbound one, so your mail server is not listening on port 25.

(To pre-empt the next question - unless you are have a particularly tight, specific purpose firewall - and if you did I posit you would not be asking this question because you would already understand the intricacies) There will be a general rule in your firewall to allow all outbound connections TO port 25 - because without it the general Internet would not work.  Your SMTP server simply takes advantage of that conneciton)

Comment: Thank you @David. Very useful response. I cannot give you a useful point because I am still brand new. I do have a question to ask as I might not be understanding this clearly due to contradictory guidance. Please go here: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu

Search for the words "Can I change port 25" and find the small paragraph written by the author. He says SMTP receiving servers (i.e. Gmail) are listening on port 25 to receive emails. So if I send emails on port 587 and block 25, how will my Gmail subscribers or any other ISP receive them?

Comment: To further add to this discussion, here's another thread where the answer was consistent with linuxbabe.com: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2246539-which-ports-are-used-for-receiving-an-email?page=1#entry-8678370

See Gerard Beekman's answer. He says "Case in point: lookup the MX records for Gmail. Those servers don't accept port 587 connections. Those mail servers are only meant to be contacted by other mail servers and thus only use port 25 for communication." For a fully working SMTP you do need port 25 open. If not, you'll not be able to send & receive 100% of your emails...

Comment: I have expanded on my answer.  My answer is consistent with the URL's you have linked above.   If SMTP port 25 is not open you will not be able to receive emails.  You will still be able to send them.  (FYI, I am qualified to answer this - I've been a Linux systems administrator for over 25 years, I have worked for a company that specializes in mail delivery and have - for 25+years run a mail server for an ISP, and currently run a mail server for a company that specialises in web hosting but also offers email service.  To boot, most of my experience is with Postfix)

Comment: This is an amazing response and I appreciate your kind and generous answer. Just a point of clarification you say in your comment if SMTP port 25 is not open you will not be able to receive emails. Like I said previously, I am not using Postfix to receive incoming messages. I have another mailbox for that at Namecheap. I am using Namecheap's MX records to accept incoming mail from my subscribers. Namecheap has port 25 open otherwise I wont receive the emails. So again, why does my Postfix need port 25 open? Because of the "OUTBOUND connection from an arbitrary port TO port 25...part?

Comment: If at the end of the day, I still need port 25 open even though Postfix doesnt accept INCOMING messages, do I need to run sudo ufw allow 25 or sudo ufw allow 25/tcp? Also, given your credentials I would LOVE to connect with you over email. I have other questions to ask. I dont mind compensating you for your time. I need to finalize the setup of my postfix and I cannot accomplish this task until I get my other questions answered. I have no one else to ask and it has been a very long 2 hard weeks getting to this stage. I am dire need of expert help. I'm not here to waste anyone's time.

Comment: I dont think there is private messaging here. Anyway we can connect on Facebook or Instagram via a private DM session so we can exchange emails? My instagram handle is digitaljoegeorge. Again, I really do need your help so I hope you are open to the idea of connecting my friend. I dont mind paying you for your assistance. If not, I completely understand. If that happens to be the case, I can also post my other postfix questions as another new question and I hope you can attend to them? Thank you again and God bless you!

Comment: I found your website link via your profile and sent a message via the contact us form. Please let me know if you got the email. Thanks!

Comment: @DigitalJoeGeorge Didnt get your message - try emailing superuser@my.host.net.nz.

Comment: You DONT need port 25 open - only 587.

Comment: THANK YOU BIG TIME. I am sending you an email shortly.